# How to store data initially and edit it dynamically in android (kotlin)?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, store

I'm creating an Android app in Kotlin for practicing English words meanings. To do that, I need to **store data in the app**, which includes a **list of English words, and for each word I need to store its meaning and other attributes**.
For example:

```
[
    {
        "word": "WORD1",
        "meaning": "M1",
        "attr1": "A11",
        "attr2": "A12",
        "attr3": "A13",
    },
    {
        "word": "WORD2",
        "meaning": "M2",
        "attr1": "A21",
        "attr2": "A22",
        "attr3": "A23",
    },
    {
        "word": "WORD3",
        "meaning": "M3",
        "attr1": "A31",
        "attr2": "A32",
        "attr3": "A33",
    },
]
```

When the app starts, it will load the stored data and **store it into collections**. Later, according to the user's inputs and selections, the app will **change some of the attributes**. Eventually, or even while the app is running, the **data needs to be stored back**.

For that I thought about using **JSON format file** that has this data, and change it dynamically. Is that possible? And if so, is this the right way to do it? Taking into account that the data needs to be changed while the app is running and restored (will this cause performance issue?)

Is there a better way to do that? and how?

---

**Update**: (after Kevin's answer below)

I think about using the JSON file to store the initial data, and the first time the app runs, it'll take the data from the JSON file and create the database with it using SQL. The JSON file will include also the version.

For that, I will store the JSON file in assets, and the app will remove it after  creating the database.

When there is an update for the JSON file (version increments), the app will update the database and remove the new JSON file after that.

Is that a good idea? Can the user access the assets file before it's remove from his device? If yes, is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually for tasks like this it's better to use SQLite, a self contained database that offers the usual SQL operations and allows your data to persist between application launches without having to manage the loading, reading and writing of a JSON file.

Comment: But how can I store the initial data in the database, if the data is needed to be in the .apk before installation? I mean I need to provide the words and the meanings before installation, and these will be in the app when installed.

Comment: maybe this question can guide you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273452/android-pre-populated-database-insert-or-pre-loaded